# How to Filter out Rows per Group after Condition Occurrs

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new to R programming and attempting to remove certain rows per a group of rows after a filtering criteria has been met.

Scenario: For each GROUP, if 2 TYPE "B" are in a row, remove all the following rows for that GROUP. The "Include in DataSet" column shows what the output should be.

Here is my example input:

```
GROUP   TYPE    Include in DataSet?
--------------------------------------------
1       A       yes
1       A       yes
1       B       yes
1       B       yes
1       B       no
2       A       yes
2       B       yes
2       B       yes
2       A       no
2       B       no
2       B       no

DF = structure(list(GROUP = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), TYPE = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", 
"B", "B"), inc = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", 
"yes", "no", "no", "no")), .Names = c("GROUP", "TYPE", "inc"), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Expected Output:

```
GROUP   TYPE    Include in DataSet?
--------------------------------------------
1       A       yes
1       A       yes
1       B       yes
1       B       yes
2       A       yes
2       B       yes
2       B       yes
```

I have tried writing some code, with no luck due to grouping issue.

```
i=1
j=2
x <- allrows
for (i in x){
  for(j in x){
    if(i==j){
      a$REMOVE=1
    }
    else{
      a$REMOVE=2
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do this by creating a new variable that identifies "double B" rows, then filter out rows after the first "double B" row in the group:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(GROUP) %>%
    # Create new variable that tests if each row and the one below it TYPE==B
    mutate(double_B = (TYPE == 'B' & lag(TYPE) == 'B')) %>%
    # Find the first row with `double_B` in each group, filter out rows after it
    filter(row_number() <= min(which(double_B == TRUE))) %>%
    # Optionally, remove `double_B` column when done with it
    select(-double_B)

# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   GROUP [2]
  GROUP TYPE  IncludeinDataSet
  <int> <chr> <chr>           
1     1 A     yes             
2     1 A     yes             
3     1 B     yes             
4     1 B     yes             
5     2 A     yes             
6     2 B     yes             
7     2 B     yes
```

As [@Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank) points out in the comment, you don't need to create the `double_B` variable: you can just test for the "double B" condition in the `which` statement inside the `filter`:

```
df %>%
    group_by(GROUP) %>%
    # Find the first row with `double_B` in each group, filter out rows after it
    filter(row_number() <= min(which(TYPE == 'B' & lag(TYPE) == 'B')))
```

Also, it will return a warning if no "double B" condition is found in a group, but will still filter properly

Comment: Re the "optionally", another way would be to use the condition without assigning a name: `df %>% group_by(GROUP) %>% filter(row_number() <= min(which(TYPE == 'B' & lag(TYPE) == 'B')))`. Btw, if there is never a double B, you'll get warnings (eg, try `min(which(FALSE))`), though I'm not sure if there's a way to get around that.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by checking the current value of 'TYPE' with the next value of 'TYPE' to find the numeric index, use `seq_len` to get the sequence from 1 to that number for subsetting the rows (inside `slice`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(GROUP) %>% 
  slice(seq_len(which((TYPE == "B") & lead(TYPE) == "B")[1] + 1))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   GROUP [2]
#  GROUP TYPE  IncludeInDataSet
#  <int> <chr> <chr>           
#1     1 A     yes             
#2     1 A     yes             
#3     1 B     yes             
#4     1 B     yes             
#5     2 A     yes             
#6     2 B     yes             
#7     2 B     yes
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(GROUP = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L), TYPE = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", 
 "B", "B"), IncludeInDataSet = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", 
  "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no")), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: great answer! can you modify this code so that within each group - once the first "B" occurs, delete everything after?

Comment: For example, is this correct?

Comment: library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(GROUP) %>% 
  slice(seq_len(which((TYPE == "B") & lead(TYPE) == "B")[1] + 0))

Comment: @stats_noob you can do that

Answer (score 2):

A different approach could be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  group_by(GROUP, rleid(TYPE)) %>%
  mutate(temp = seq_along(TYPE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(GROUP) %>%
  filter(row_number() <= min(which(TYPE == "B" & temp == 2))) %>%
  select(GROUP, TYPE, IncludeInDataSet)
```

Comment: Great answer! If I want to modify your answer so that in each group - all rows are deleted after the first "B", is this correct?

Comment: df %>%
  group_by(GROUP, rleid(TYPE)) %>%
  mutate(temp = seq_along(TYPE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(GROUP) %>%
  filter(row_number() <= min(which(TYPE == "B" & temp == 1))) %>%
  select(GROUP, TYPE, IncludeInDataSet)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R solution:

```
subset(DF, as.logical(ave(DF$TYPE,DF$GROUP, FUN= function(x) 
  seq_along(x) <= which((sequence(rle(x=="B")$length) * (x=="B")) %in% 2)[1])))
#   GROUP TYPE inc
# 1     1    A yes
# 2     1    A yes
# 3     1    B yes
# 4     1    B yes
# 6     2    A yes
# 7     2    B yes
# 8     2    B yes
```

Comment: Great answer! If I want to modify your answer so that in each group - all rows are deleted after the first "B", is this correct?

Comment: subset(DF, as.logical(ave(DF$TYPE,DF$GROUP, FUN= function(x) 
    seq_along(x) <= which((sequence(rle(x=="B")$length) * (x=="B")) %in% 1)[1])))