# R: Removing All Rows After Condition Is Met

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset:

```
id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
col1 = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0)
col2 = c("A", "B", "A","A", "B", "A","A", "B", "A","A", "B", "A","A", "B", "A", "B")
my_data = data.frame(id, col1, col2)
my_data$row_num = 1:nrow(my_data)
```

**For each unique ID - whenever col1 = 1 OR col2 = A, I want to delete all remaining rows that occur AFTER this condition (i.e. keep the first occurrence).**

I found this question over here ([How to Filter out Rows per Group after Condition Occurrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766382/how-to-filter-out-rows-per-group-after-condition-occurrs)) in which an answer to a similar a question is provided. I tried to adapt this answer for my problem:

```
library(dplyr) 

my_data %>%
    group_by(id) %>% 
    slice(seq_len(which((col1 == 1) | (col2 == "A"))[1]))
```

**Can someone please confirm if I have done this correctly?** I am not sure if I have correctly inserted the OR statement within the "slice" function.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use `first`?What is your expected output?

Comment: Try `my_data[as.logical(ave(Reduce(paste0, my_data[2:3]), my_data$id, FUN=\(x) cumsum(x == '1A') == 0)), ]`.

Comment: @ Jay.sf: thank you for your answer! is the approach I suggested incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `filter` based on all the `row_number` before the conditions happen using `which` like this:

```r
id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
col1 = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0)
col2 = c("A", "B", "A","A", "B", "A","A", "B", "A","A", "B", "A","A", "B", "A", "B")
my_data = data.frame(id, col1, col2)
my_data$row_num = 1:nrow(my_data)

library(dplyr)
my_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(row_number() <= min(which((col1 == 1) | (col2 == "A"))))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>      id  col1 col2  row_num
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <int>
#> 1     1     0 A           1
#> 2     2     0 B           5
#> 3     2     0 A           6
#> 4     3     1 A          10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @ Quinten: thank you so much for your answer! Can you please comment - do you think the code I have written is correct?

Comment: Hi @stats_noob, I do think it works! I tried some calculations with different values and it seems to work in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's some tidy magic that can go the job but here's the "dumb" approach by partitioning the dataset by ID and looping through each of the parts:

```
filtered_data <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=0, ncol=4))
colnames(filtered_data) <- colnames(my_data)

rows_added <- 0
for(id in 1:3) {
  relevant_data <- my_data[my_data$id == id,]
  for(row in 1:nrow(my_data)) {
      rows_added <- rows_added + 1
      filtered_data[rows_added,] <- relevant_data[row,]
      jump_condition <- relevant_data[row, "col1"] == 1 | relevant_data[row, "col2"] == "A"
      if(jump_condition) {
        break
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: @ David: Thank you for your answer! Can you please comment - is my code wrong?

Comment: @stats_noob Not sure. The OR operator looks okay but I don't know much about tidy functions so I'm not sure. Does it do the job properly on the test data?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! To me it seems correct, but I generally tend to be wrong about these things (lol!).

Comment: @stats_noob tests are the most common way for software developpers to check if their code is correct. If you're in still doubt, make one more test case until you're not!